# Missing argument in SGS simulation of HPGL

Tags: python, kriging

Here is a simple example to test the Sequential Gaussian Simulation in open geostatistics library HPGL. I use the following file as hard data for the kriging:

[NEW_TEST_PROP.INC](https://github.com/hpgl/hpgl/blob/cae3489b4935bf0e1e76d02d61d9791b365db77c/src/dist/misc/test/test_data/NEW_TEST_PROP.INC)

here is my simple code:

```
from geo_bsd import *    
size = (55, 52, 1)
grid = SugarboxGrid(55, 52, 1)
prop = load_cont_property(NEW_TEST_PROP.inc, -99, size)
cov1 = CovarianceModel(type=1, ranges=(10,10,10), sill=0.4)
sgs_result = sgs_simulation(prop, grid,radiuses = (20,20,20),max_neighbours = 12,cov_model = cov1,seed=3439275)
```

However, I always get the following argument error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 5, in

sgs_result = sgs_simulation(prop, grid,radiuses = (20,20,20),max_neighbours = 12,cov_model = cov1,seed=3439275)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geo_bsd/geo.py", line 272, in new_f
return f(*args, **kargs)

TypeError: sgs_simulation() takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)
```

I know it is trivial but I just cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have entered 6 arguments for the sgs_simulation function and it says you need 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthew is right. This is the function def:

```
def sgs_simulation(prop, grid, cdf_data, radiuses, max_neighbours, cov_model, seed, kriging_type="sk", mean=None, use_harddata = True, use_regions=False, region_size = None, mask=None, force_single_thread=False, force_parallel=False, min_neighbours = 0, **params)
```

It has 7 required positional arguments, 9 optional keyword arguments, and an undefined number of other keyword arguments (which aren't used, for some reason).

It looks like you're not passing the 3rd `cdf_data` argument.

Comment: You both are right. I missed the cdf_data argument. For my defense, in the manual is written that `cdf_data=None` is default. Anyway, here is the complete command `sgs_result = sgs_simulation(prop=prop,grid= grid,radiuses = (20,20,1),max_neighbours = 12,cov_model = cov1,seed=3439275,kriging_type="ok",cdf_data=calc_cdf(prop))`

Comment: Scrox, note that the module's `sgs_simulation()` does some magic with its inputs using a decorator (see https://github.com/hpgl/hpgl/blob/cae3489b4935bf0e1e76d02d61d9791b365db77c/src/geo_bsd/geo.py#L252). You can't normally call a Python function that takes keyword arguments this way – `prop`, `grid` etc would go into the keyword arguments and the positional arguments would be empty.